# Ccalling receive data function on Vb

Tags: vb.net, vba, serial-port

I have gone through the Link vb serial communication. They ar eusing below function for getting data. My question are as follows

1. How to call this below function on VB
2. My data from serial are CSV value how to separate and display in a text box
3. Updating the text box values?

   Function ReceiveSerialData() As String
           ' Receive strings from a serial port. 
           Dim returnStr As String = ""

   ```
       Dim com3 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
       Try
           com3 = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM3")
           com3.ReadTimeout = 10000
           Do
               Dim Incoming As String = com3.ReadLine()
               If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                   Exit Do
               Else
                   returnStr &= Incoming & vbCrLf
               End If
           Loop
       Catch ex As TimeoutException
           returnStr = "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
       Finally
           If com3 IsNot Nothing Then com3.Close()
       End Try

       Return returnStr
   End Function
   ```

MY compelte code aS BELOW

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading

Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim myPort As Array
        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        PortComboBox.Items.AddRange(CType(myPort, Object()))

        BaudComboBox.Items.Add(9600)
        BaudComboBox.Items.Add(19200)
        BaudComboBox.Items.Add(38400)
        BaudComboBox.Items.Add(57600)
        BaudComboBox.Items.Add(115200)
        ConnectButton.Enabled = True
        DisconnectButton.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        Timer1.Start()
        Receive.Text = ReceiveSerialData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ConnectButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ConnectButton.Click
        SerialPort1.PortName = PortComboBox.Text
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = CInt(BaudComboBox.Text)
        SerialPort1.Open()
        Timer1.Start()

        'lblMessage.Text = PortComboBox.Text & " Connected."
        ConnectButton.Enabled = False
        DisconnectButton.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisconnectButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DisconnectButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()
        DisconnectButton.Enabled = False
        ConnectButton.Enabled = True
    End Sub



    Function ReceiveSerialData() As String
        ' Receive strings from a serial port. 
        Dim returnStr As String = ""

        Dim com3 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
        Try
            com3 = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM3")
            com3.ReadTimeout = 10000
            Do
                Dim Incoming As String = com3.ReadLine()
                If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    returnStr &= Incoming & vbCrLf
                End If
            Loop
        Catch ex As TimeoutException
            returnStr = "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
        Finally
            If com3 IsNot Nothing Then com3.Close()
        End Try

        Return returnStr
    End Function



End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to create a short sample for you but you need to understand threading and serial working for this. follow the steps to create this sample

add new class module to your code with name mySerial and past following code in it (replace code)

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class dataReceivedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Private m_StringData As String

    Public Sub New(strData As String)
        Me.m_StringData = strData
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property ReceivedData As String
        Get
            Return m_StringData
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class mySerial
    Private ReadThread As Thread
    Dim SPort As SerialPort
    Private syncContext As SynchronizationContext
    Public Event DataReceived(Sender As Object, ByVal e As dataReceivedEventArgs)

    Public Sub New(ByVal COMMPORT As String, ByVal BaudRate As Integer)
        Me.New(COMMPORT, BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
    End Sub    

    Public Sub New(ByVal _COMMPORT As String, ByVal _BaudRate As Integer, ByVal _Parity As Parity, ByVal _DataBits As Integer, ByVal _StopBits As StopBits)
        SPort = New SerialPort
        With SPort
            .PortName = _COMMPORT
            .BaudRate = _BaudRate
            .Parity = _Parity
            .DataBits = _DataBits
            .StopBits = _StopBits
            .Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff
            .DtrEnable = True
            .RtsEnable = True
            .NewLine = vbCrLf
        End With
        Me.syncContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext
        ReadThread = New Thread(AddressOf ReadPort)
    End Sub

    Public Sub OpenPort()
        If Not SPort.IsOpen Then
            SPort.Open()
            SPort.DiscardNull = True
            SPort.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII
            ReadThread.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub ClosePort()
        If SPort.IsOpen Then
            SPort.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadPort()
        Do While SPort.IsOpen
            Dim ReceviceData As String = String.Empty
            Do While SPort.BytesToRead <> 0 And SPort.IsOpen And ReceviceData.Length < 5000
                Try
                    ReceviceData &= SPort.ReadExisting()
                    Thread.Sleep(100)
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            Loop
            If ReceviceData <> String.Empty Then
                'raise event and provide data
                syncContext.Post(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf onDataReceived), ReceviceData)
            End If
            Thread.Sleep(500)
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub onDataReceived(ByVal ReceivedData As String)
        RaiseEvent DataReceived(Me, New dataReceivedEventArgs(ReceivedData))
    End Sub
End Class
```

this is class which will work as wrapper class for you, now to make it work add a form with name frmSerial and a textBox with name txtData and set multiline=true, scrollbars=both, now past following code in it

```
Public Class frmSerial
    Dim WithEvents _Serial As mySerial

    Private Sub frmSerial_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        _Serial.ClosePort()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmSerial_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        _Serial = New mySerial("COM1", 9600)
        _Serial.OpenPort()
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Serial_DataReceived(Sender As Object, e As dataReceivedEventArgs) Handles _Serial.DataReceived
        txtData.Text &= e.ReceivedData
        txtData.SelectionStart = txtData.Text.Length
        txtData.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub
End Class
```

hop this helps you and people like you

Comment: For your code i need to make a Combobox . I never seen control forms expect the text box

Comment: i asked you to put text box with multi line on why you need combobox